# Redirect Printf to UART on PIC24F Curiosity

Tags: uart, microchip, mplab, pic24

I'm trying to redirect Printf to UART to output to a console like CoolTerm etc,
without success, I'm using the "PIC24F Curiosity Development Board"
with PIC24FJ128GA204, MPLAB X v5.25, MCC v3.85.1

after search google and microchip forums, I have got up with this
[On Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KngOYpZ2HRc)
[On Microchip](https://microchipdeveloper.com/mcu1101:project-12)
[DM240004 docs](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/DM240004)

UART Settings:

[image: UART Settings]

Pin Manager:

[image: Pin manager]

CoolTerm doesn't even recognize the board as a serial port.

I expect to be able to print out from the board with printf to CoolTerm, TeraTerm, etc.

Comment: *"CoolTerm doesn't even recognize the board as a serial port."* --  This statement concerns me. Unlike e.g. USB, there is nothing to "recognize" with a serial port. The terminal simply opens the serial port and displays any data received on it. Are you sure the baud rates match, and you've correctly wired RX-TX and TX-RX (e.g. with a crossover cable if necessary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Arduino, Teensy or other boards, on your Curiosity the USB is not an emulated serial port.

According to the screenshots on your question, you're trying to set up a UART on Port C. If that's what you want to do you'll have to look at your board [schematic](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002534a.pdf) and connect those pins to a TTL serial port. If you want to see the *printf* outputs on the screen of your PC you need either a TTL to RS232 (if your computer still have a good old serial port, which I very much doubt) or a USB-to-serial adaptor with the appropriate levels (check the datasheet or just get [one](https://stak.com/USB_to_TTL_Serial_Adapter__FTDI_FT232RL_chipset__3.3V_and_5V_compatible) that can work on both 3.3V or 5V).

As far as I can tell, the micro USB port on your board can only be used for programing and/or debugging.